# Are the requirements for the windows phone 8.1 emulator the same as 8?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator, windows-phone-8.1

I've been looking around and i'm not sure if they both have the same requirements.
I had Visual Studio 2012 with the most recent update working fine with the Windows Phone 8 emulator on my Windows 8 (64 bit) computer.
Then, I installed Windows 8.1 and Visual Studios 2013 with the most recent update but now it won't let me download the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator.
It says "This computer does not support the windows phone emulator, which requires 64-bit edition of Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that supports Hyper-V".
Is there different requirements for the 8.1 emulator or is there something I need to trouble shoot?

Comment: It requires 64-bit edition of windows 8.1 pro and a computer that supports hyper-v. Do you have those?

Answer (score 2):

Requirement for running Windows Phone 8.1 emulators are really similar to running WP8 emulators. The only difference is that you need now Windows 8.1, previously it was Windows 8, and you have to use Visual Studio 2013, previously you could use Visual Studio 2012 as well.

Detailed requirements for running Windows Phone 8.1 emulators:

- **Windows 8.1 x64 Pro** or **Enterprise** edition
- **Visual Studio 2013** with **[Update 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/04/the-release-candidate-for-visual-studio-2013-update-2.aspx)** installed, currently available as RC
- **CPU that supports SLAT instructions**, basically any recent Core-i3/5/7 has it.
- enabled hardware virtualization in BIOS (VT-x/AMD-V)

Specifically to your question, have you installed Pro edition of Windows 8.1 and also 64bit version?

Comment: I think my problem might be with Windows. When I downloaded the 8.1 64 bit update, I didn't check if it was the pro version but in the systems menu it only says "Windows 8.1".

Comment: The Windows ISO file contains both versions, the installed version depends on the key you use during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer must meet the following requirements:

**BIOS**

In the BIOS, the following features must be supported:

> - Hardware-assisted virtualization.
> - Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).
> - Hardware-based Data Execution Prevention (DEP).
> - RAM 4 GB or more.

**Operating system**

> - Windows 8
> - 64-bit
> - Pro edition or higher

You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524.aspx#windows).