# Deploy app to manually started windows phone 8.1 emulator

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am facing [a known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432) when I try to deploy my app to the windows phone 8.1 emulator from visual studio 2013. The issue is `Unable to load LocBootPresets` during the startup of the emulator.

As a workaround I tried starting the emulator manually, which works.

Now I want to deploy my app from visual studio 2013 to the running emulator image, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue from [kb2927432](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2927432)

```
Assume that you have Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 and Windows Phone 8.0 tools 
installed on Windows 8. The Windows Phone 8.1 emulators are available. In this 
situation, you cannot run a Windows Phone 8.0 application by pressing F5. 
Additionally, you receive the following error message:

Windows Phone Emulator is unable to verify that the virtual machine is running:

Unable to load DLL 'LocBootPresets': The specified module could not be found.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I think problem with OS, because I catch the same problem on Windows Server 2012. Try to use Windows 8.1 or Server 2012 R2.

Comment: I think it's impossible to deploy apps to phone 8.1 emulator from Windows 8. Because if you go to new project you find out that there is no universal apps template and Windows Apps template require Windows 8.1 or higher installed. Furthermore, if you create new Windows Phone Apps under Windows 8 it will 8.0 version not 8.1 and after you change apps version to 8.1 version under solution property solution will say that you should upgrade your computer to Windows 8.1 or higher. But I don't know why it's impossible to deploy 8.0 application on Phone 8.1 Emulator from Windows 8 and server 2012.

Comment: Also look at this tread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048630/are-the-requirements-for-the-windows-phone-8-1-emulator-the-same-as-8