# Windows Phone 8.1 Emulator Error in Windows 8.1 Pro 64-Bit - Surface Pro 3

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

Just 2 weeks ago I received my `Surface Pro 3 i7 256GB HDD, 8GB RAM 64-bit Windows 8.1 Professional` (see image) [image].

On this, I am trying to install the Windows 8.1 Phone Emulator but it throws an error (see attached)

[image]

I have **Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop Version 12.0.3 Update 3** installed. Hyper-V is also installed from Program & Features. Below is the coreinfo -v information as gathered

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4650U CPU @ 1.70GHz 2.30GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: XXXXXXXX
HYPERVISOR      -  Hypervisor is present
VMX             *  Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *  Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

Can anyone guide. Appreciate!

Edit: Just to add, I have managed to install the **Windows SDK for 8.1** successfully without any issues.

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you running?

Comment: @jbutler483 It is mentioned in my post, seems you missed. I am using `Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop Version 12.0.3 Update 3`

Comment: Try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23048880/3436942 and/or http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff626524.aspx#windows

Comment: @jbutler483 Thanks I saw both the links but unfortunately it didn't work out for me that is why I posted here for guidance

Comment: you could always try downloading a trial for MS VS professional? I don't think it's your PC in this situation. But I thought *for Windows Desktop* meant you could only create desktop applications (not others)? :(

Comment: @jbutler483 as per the Channel 9 and Microsoft site, `Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop` is needed. But, let me check again I might be wrong.

Comment: *The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are installed with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 2 or later and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later.* - http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk

Comment: @jbutler483 you might be right. May be while downloading I chose Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop instead of Windows. Let me download and try to install

Comment: no problem - I know from experience just how hard it is to get the EXACT version of VS you need! :)

Comment: @jbutler483 I worked perfectly. It seems I messed up with the version. Would you answer it so that I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the wrong version of Visual Studio installed. According to the Windows 8 Phone Docs:

`The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are installed with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 2 or later and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 or later.` - [Documentation](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

Try installing  **Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows** instead.

Have fun creating Win8 Phone apps!!